# why marker's location in google map set to off road?

Tags: google-maps, swift3, location, marker

I've using MKMapView in which I found the current location lat-long is not fetched properly most of the time it shows off road location. That is the reason that I replace my MKMapView with GoogleMap but I faced the same issues in that also

Reference :

[image]

The reason I found is IOS device is providing me lat-long off the road which I need to fix.The image contains the path from "City bicycle ride" but in a real ride, I'm also facing the same issue.

what to do to set the marker at the center position of the road in GoogleMap?

Note: I'm using swift 3.

Code in use:

```
//------------------------------------------------------

//MARK: - user Location

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        let locationArray = locations as NSArray
        let locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
        curruntLocation = locationObj.coordinate // storing in global variable
        //post notification to update the currunt location in specific view controller
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kPNUserLocationDidChange, object: nil)
    } 
}

//------------------------------------------------------

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    curruntHeading = Double(newHeading.trueHeading) // storing in global variable
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kPNUserLocationDidChange, object: nil)
}

//------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm experimenting the same problem. The current location is off road very often and I used approx the same code as your. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not actually. I've zoomed out the map a bit so that my pin covers the whole road, this works most of the time but not all the time.